# How to install `aide` without `aide-common` in debian?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, auditd, aide

Per [this post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FileIntegrityAIDE),

> Newer versions of Ubuntu (including 14.04) come with two packages for
> AIDE:
>
> ```
> aide, with the aide command and manual page, and little else
>
> aide-common, with a wrapper around that command, configuration files with rules, and cron configuration files that will cause AIDE to be run nightly
> ```
>
> If your AIDE is bundled like this, attempts to run the aide command
> directly will fail with the message:
>
> Couldn't open file
> /var/lib/aide/please-dont-call-aide-without-parameters/aide.db for
> reading
>
> even when parameters are supplied.
>
> The configuration files are in different places, and to configure and
> use AIDE, the executables from aide-common must be used instead:
> aideinit, aide.wrapper, update-aide.conf, and aide-attributes.

In Debian 10,when you `apt install aide`,`aide-common` also be installed.
How to install `aide` without `aide-common` in debian?

Answer (score 3):

From `apt-cache depends aide` we can see that it's only reccomended:

```
[~]$ apt-cache depends aide
aide
  Conflicts: aide-dynamic
  Conflicts: aide-xen
  Recommends: aide-common
  Suggests: figlet
```

If it said `Depends: aide-common` it would be a hard requirement. Recommends is only a soft dependency, so you can choose to ignore it.

If we from there go on to `man apt-get`, to learn how apt-get works and search for `recommends` we find this:

> ```
>    --no-install-recommends
>       Do not consider recommended packages as a dependency for
>       installing. Configuration Item: APT::Install-Recommends.
> ```

So the command `apt-get install --no-install-recommends aide` should install aide without installing `aide-common`.

Comment: And for more complex cases than this one (where there's a choice of packages dependencies and the wrong choice is selected), this could be used `apt-get install aide aide-common-` which will emit a warning because it's not installed but will also prevent it to install.